# Would binary logistic regression or multinomial logistic regression be more appropriate for this study?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, multinomial-logit

I am doing a study on the financing behaviour of firms and my dependent variables (financing behaviour) will be binary. Eg. firms that sought debt financing = 1 and firms that did not seek debt financing = 0.

If I am wanting to test three dependent variables (firms that sought debt, firms that sought equity, firms that sought debt and equity), what would be the best regression model to use? Would a multinomial regression work or will doing 3 binary regression models function?

Comment: Is your response variable binary or not? First you say it’s binary. Then you say there are three options. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi. There are three dependent variables (debt, equity, debt + equity). The data for each variable is either 1 or 0. For example, if a firm sought debt = 1, if not = 0. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: How would you set up your logistic or multinomial logistic regressions?